# Curl showing but not returning data

Tags: php, curl, return

I'm trying to write a simple curl function that queries the freegeoip.net site with the IP address of a site visitor.  This is usually done by typing "https://freegeoip.net/csv/{IP Address}" in the browser address line.  The site then processes the request and returns a csv file that can be opened or saved.  I'm trying to access the csv data directly so that I can parse and use it.  This is the code that I am using:

```
<?php

$ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$geturl = "http://freegeoip.net/csv/".$ip;
$data = curl_get_contents($geturl);
echo ("<br>Data = '".$data."'<br>");

function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if($ch)
    {
        $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Curl not loaded!<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

This is what I am getting back:

***.***.**.**,US,United States,ST,State,City,?????,America/New_York,**.*****,-**.****,***

Data = '1'

As you can see, my function is accessing and showing the csv data but not returning it to the $data variable.  Apparently, the data is being shown when the "curl_exec($ch);" command is being executed.  I want to parse and use the returned data but can't until the data is returned.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you just tell the whole internet your address?

Comment: It was a random input for demonstration purposes but I'll make it more anonymous if that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) says:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, `FALSE` on failure.

What it doesn't say is explained in the documentation page of [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), on the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option:

> **Option:** `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`
>   **Set value to:** `TRUE` to return the transfer as a string of the return value of [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) instead of outputting it out directly.

That is, by default, `curl_exec()` outputs the body of the response it gets. In order to make it return the value and not output it, you have to use [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks you Axiac.  Clearly, I missed that in the documentation of curl_exec().

Answer (score 0):

you need to add following line before curl_exec other wise the result will output instead of returning it to $tmp variable.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't telling Curl that you want the data to be returned rather than output:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://freegeoip.net/csv/".$ip);
 $csv=curl_exec($ch);
```

But this is rather verbose when, depending on your config, you can:

```
 $csv=file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/csv/".$ip);
```